# Making two HTML forms into one

Tags: php, html

So I got this form which saves text into a session variable with PHP. I got another form which makes all my session variables save into my database. 
I'm trying to make it more efficient bij making the 2 forms into one form with one button. Here is my complete page code:

```
    <?php
            session_start();
            if( $_SESSION['myusername'] == "")
            {
                    header('Location: index.php');
                }
    ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <style>body {background-image:url("stopphp.jpg");}</style>
    </head>

    <?php 
        if($_POST)
     {

     // $_SESSION["textarea"] = "";

        $_SESSION["textarea"] = $_POST["textarea"];
        header("Location:stop.php");
     }

        if($_GET)
     {

        $_SESSION["klantnummer"] = $_GET["klantnummer"];
        header("Location:stop.php");
     }

        if($_GET)
     {

        $_SESSION["klantnaam"] = $_GET["klantnaam"];
        header("Location:stop.php");
     }

       $textarea = $_SESSION["textarea"];
    ?>

        <div id="notities">
            <span style="font-family:Cursive;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;text-transform:none;color:000000;">Notities:</span>

<p>
     <form action="" method="post">
        <textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="textarea"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Sla tekst op">
    </form> 

 <p>

        <form action="writeaway.php" method="post">
              <input type="submit" value="Bij einde gesprek gelieve hier te drukken">
        </form>
        </div>


</html>
```

All suggestions are appreciated, sorry for the nooby question.

EDIT:

here is my writeaway code:

```
    <?php
            session_start();
            if( $_SESSION['myusername'] == "")
            {
                    header('Location: index.php');
                }
    ?>
<html>
    <?php
        $date=date_create();
        $_SESSION["stopdatum"] = date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
    ?>

    <?php include 'database.php'; ?>

    <?php
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO suplog (login,sstart,sstop,remark,klantnummer,klantnaam) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['myusername'])."',
                                                                          '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['startdatum'])."',
                                                                          '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['stopdatum'])."',
                                                                          '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['textarea'])."',
                                                                          '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['klantnummer'])."',
                                                                          '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['klantnaam'])."')"); ?>

    <?php
session_destroy();
?>
    <?php header('Location: start.php'); ?>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to specify what the problem is?

Comment: May this url might help you.[http://bavotasan.com/2009/processing-multiple-forms-on-one-page-with-php/]

Comment: At the bottom of the page I got 2 forms, they are connected to 2 seperate buttons, i'm trying to make them into one form and one button which will do both the actions.

Comment: Why you want to save session by another form. Let me tell you the case, as whenever you start session on a page , it gets initiated, now post anywhere i mean any url that will be handle by the corresponding php page, use session there also and get the Session values there. Validate data and write them in your DB

Comment: Just put everything between one form tag and handle what you want when the form is posted?

Comment: Can anyone give me a code sample by chance to help me out since I just don't get it. Thanks for the kind responses.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get your problem...

But you should try to assign your session variables with the values in the same step like you write them into a database!  In your case in writeaway.php... Why would you do that in two different steps?

Hope that helps

Comment: Could you give me a code sample on what that would look like as i simply don't get it. I'm new to all this, all little bits are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh well let me say it in other words, you use just one form, and at he moment you handle on form in the same file and the other one in writeaway.php. Just copy the assignment of session values to your writeaway and do it there, so you need just one form and you can do the assignment directly before you write the values to the database

Comment: In what line in writeaway.php do I handle a form, and which form? Again sorry for my noobyness.